# issues making PDF's searchable on Google

Tags: c#, pdf, mongodb

I have been researching everywhere and I just cannot seem to find out how to make my documents searchable on Google without adding them directly to my website. Here is the my goal... if someone could help me to achieve it I would so GREATLY APPRECIATE it... as I am a bit frustrated at this point.

Goal:

I need to make my document library searchable by Google. I've gone down the route of using SharePoint to hold my documents but this has been ruled out as we need a user name and password in order for you retrieve the documents hence Google cannot get in. So we changed routes and decided to use MONGO db which so far I am still not able to get my PDF to be searchable ( mongo requires no login credentials, however it is not on the DMZ, it lives behind the firewall but there is a port to allow access into it...

Steps. 1st I am using ASP.net C#
2nd I have a pdf in mongo that is password free and Google accessible
3rd I have a site map that I’ve submitted to Google with the page these pdfs are linked on.
4th. I am using a linkbutton to access the files from Mongo and from one  that is directly to a pdf within  my site.
So far there here are results and details:

I have 4 test cases...

Case 1: PDF in mongo with the text in the pdf which seems to be only select all (locked down) retrieving via a linkbutton ( this one is not searchable)

Mongo pdf

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbClick" runat="server" onclick="lbClick_Click">Click Me</asp:LinkButton>
```

Case 2: PDF with the text in the pdf able to copy any part of the content being retrieve via a linkbutton (this one is now searchable on Google, but is not an option for my site to house all the PDF’s within the website, it was just a test to make sure we can search a pdf)

PDF on site

```
   <asp:LinkButton ID="lbnOnSite" runat="server" onclick="lbnOnSite_Click">Click Here</asp:LinkButton>
```

Case 3: PDF with text in the pdf able to copy any part of the content being retrieved via an  tag ( this one oddly is not searchable and I am very confused why, I would of thought if any this one would work no problem after everything I have read)

```
test searchable pdf 
<a href="/endobiop.pdf"> Click Me</a>
```

Case 4: PDF in Mongo text in the pdf able to copy any part of the content being retrieved via a linkbutton. ( this one is not searchable)

```
 Mongo Test 2 
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" 
    onclick="LinkButton1_Click">Click Me</asp:LinkButton>
```

The only other thing I would like to add is that out of all the research I’ve done it seems as if it takes time on Google to do the indexing of the files and that the PDF needs to be opened once on the site…  So the question I have is how do you have to wait? 1 week, 1 month, 1 year, a lifetime… basically I have no idea when I know my test failed.

Comment: All your button clicks are doing HTTP posts to get the data.  To my knowledge, a search engine would not follow those "links" (they're not links - a button is intended to DO something. This is the idea behind a http POST as opposed to a GET - a normal link, which is intended to be idempotent).

Comment: It sounds like you'd need to generate a page with direct GET links to all of the PDFs you have.  It doesn't matter how/where they're stored, so long as they're returned to google.  In terms of how often, it should be pretty quick the first time.  Google decides how often to index based on how often your content changes.